# crash into /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10

When I opened the ubuntu I got this crash as mentioned in the screenshot:
[image: gnome-session-crash]

The output of /var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 15 09:14:01 OptiPlex-3020 CRON[14496]: (root) CMD (   test -x 

/etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Feb 15 09:14:20 OptiPlex-3020 anacron[705]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Feb 15 09:14:20 OptiPlex-3020 anacron[705]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Feb 15 09:14:59 OptiPlex-3020 update-notifier[13312]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Feb 15 09:14:59 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-shell[4817]: value "-1.000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'width' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 15 09:14:59 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-shell[4817]: value "-1.000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'height' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 15 09:14:59 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-shell[4817]: value "-1.000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'width' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 15 09:14:59 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-shell[4817]: value "-1.000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'height' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 15 09:15:16 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-shell[4817]: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenu' on the module 'windowPreview'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Feb 15 09:15:17 OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [  407.923705] traps: apport-gtk[14534] general protection ip:7f5f13ecb194 sp:7fffe6c15380 error:0 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.1[7f5f13e9a000+52000]
Feb 15 09:15:57 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-terminal.[14576]: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Feb 15 09:15:57 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service'
Feb 15 09:15:57 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[2787]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Feb 15 09:15:57 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-terminal-[14579]: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Feb 15 09:15:57 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Feb 15 09:15:57 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[2787]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Feb 15 09:16:36 OptiPlex-3020 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4817]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x3800084 (syslog [Re)
Feb 15 09:17:01 OptiPlex-3020 CRON[14638]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 15 09:17:20 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus'
Feb 15 09:17:20 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Feb 15 09:17:20 OptiPlex-3020 nautilus[14644]: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Feb 15 09:17:21 OptiPlex-3020 dbus[686]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Feb 15 09:17:21 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Feb 15 09:17:21 OptiPlex-3020 nautilus[14644]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Feb 15 09:17:21 OptiPlex-3020 dbus[686]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Feb 15 09:17:21 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine' unit='zeitgeist.service'
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[2787]: Starting Zeitgeist activity log service...
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer' unit='zeitgeist-fts.service'
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine'
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[2787]: Started Zeitgeist activity log service.
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[2787]: Starting Zeitgeist full-text search indexer...
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 zeitgeist-daemon[14662]: #033[31m[08:17:27.365997 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:334: Failed to execute child process “zeitgeist-datahub” (No such file or directory)
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 zeitgeist-daemon[14662]: #033[31m[08:17:27.366081 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 zeitgeist-daemon[14662]: #033[31m[08:17:27.366151 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 dbus-daemon[2837]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer'
Feb 15 09:17:27 OptiPlex-3020 systemd[2787]: Started Zeitgeist full-text search indexer.
Feb 15 09:17:33 OptiPlex-3020 gnome-terminal.[14683]: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Feb 15 09:17:50 OptiPlex-3020 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4817]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x3800084 (syslog (~/)
```

How can I fix this?